# QAudioBuffer providing different data of the same song in different computers

Tags: qt

I'm creating a music player for PC. I want to visualize the FFT of the song. I've crated an entire class that buffers 1024 points of data does the FFT and displays it (this is handled by another class). My program was developed in my laptop which uses Debian Testing x64. My work pc uses Centos 7 x64. When I compiled my program (both use Qt 5.7.0) on my work PC the FFT visualization was garbage. Snooping into my code I found that the sample type provided by QAudioBuffer from QAudioProbe was Signed (in my work PC) while it was float in my Laptop. Here is the code that is called whenever QAudioProbe emits that data has been buffered:

```
void SpectrumController::setAudioBuffer(QAudioBuffer buffer){

    // Used to momentarily stop the process.
    if (!enableBuffering) return;

    // Only process stereo frames
    if (buffer.format().channelCount() != 2) return;

    if (buffer.format().sampleType() == QAudioFormat::SignedInt){

        //qWarning() << "Signed";
        QAudioBuffer::S16S *data = buffer.data<QAudioBuffer::S16S>();
        bufferData(data,buffer.frameCount());

    }
    else if (buffer.format().sampleType() == QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt){

        //qWarning() << "Unsigned";
        QAudioBuffer::S16U *data = buffer.data<QAudioBuffer::S16U>();
        bufferData(data,buffer.frameCount());

    }
    else if(buffer.format().sampleType() == QAudioFormat::Float){

        //qWarning() << "Float";
        QAudioBuffer::S32F *data = buffer.data<QAudioBuffer::S32F>();
        bufferData(data,buffer.frameCount());

    }

}

template<typename T>
void SpectrumController::bufferData(T *data, qint32 N){
    for (qint32 i = 0; i < N; i++){
        //if (qAbs(data[i].left) > largest){largest = qAbs(data[i].left); qDebug() << "Largest" << largest;}
        //currentBuffer << ((qreal)data[i].left/(largest));
        //qWarning() << "Added data" << currentBuffer.last();
        currentBuffer << data[i].left;

        if (datcounter < 100000){
            *writer << data[i].left;
            *writer << "\n";
            datcounter++;
        }
        else if (writeFile->isOpen()){
            qWarning() << "Closed file";
            writeFile->close();
        }

        if (currentBuffer.size() == FFT_SIZE){
            dataBuffer << currentBuffer;
            currentBuffer.clear();
            if (!isRunning) run();
        }
```

What I ended up doing is writing, to a file, the first 100.000 points of data gathered by both my laptop and my work PC in order to plot them.

This is what I've got

[image: Comparison of plotted data]

What I think is that difference is in the base system's handling of the the mp3, which, in turn, is what Qt uses. I think is gstreamer. Centos uses a much older version. The plot on the right corresponds to my laptop while the plot on the left corresponds to my work pc.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or am I just stuck with no way of accessising the raw audio data correctly?

UPDATE:
Even though this is not a Fix or anything like that, the data in the other channel (data[i].right) did have more appropiate data. I'm using the right channnel, for now.